# System clear Property doesn't work. How can it be?

Tags: java

I really don't understand!

I run unit tests which contains cod:

```
  String progDir = "prog.dir";
  System.clearProperty(progDir);
  System.out.println(System.getProperty(progDir));
```

And on console I see prog dir path. Although there must be null.

I setting this variable in setUp block. This is junit test. This variable need for all other test but not for that, so I tried to clean it in the start of this test method. If I remove setting of this  var from setUp block this test will pass.

System.setProperty work fine.

How can it be?
Thanx

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're clearing the same key as the one you're retrieving?  (It looks like there might be a typo/bug in your example between `progDir` and `osprovDir`).  Otherwise, it might be worth seeing what the return value of the `clearProperty()` call is - this should be the previously-mapped value (if any).

Comment: Are there other threads which might be setting that property?

Comment: I just ran your code and got it printed out `null`.

Comment: If you got a Java security manager enabled, you need specific permissions to succeed. Your call requires `PropertyPermission "key", "read,write"`.

Comment: Sorry. When I wrote this post I whan't to change realy name of variable, but made mistake. In cod it's ok. System.clearProperty(progDir) return null(althouhght it might be value of progDir). But System.out.println(System.getProperty(progDir)); write the valye of progDir.

Comment: MicSim: If it was security, an exception would be thrown when trying to clear the property.

Comment: @MicSim -- then he'd get a SecurityException, and the print statement would be skipped.

Comment: MicSim, yes I redefined sequrity manager for some purpose. But, as I understand, sequrityException in this case has be throug. Or not?

Comment: Andrzej Doyle the mistake only in post. Thank you.

Comment: Ernest Friedman-Hill 99% that there are no any other thread that can change this var becouse it's write in the begin of test method. Although this System variable sets int the setUP to default value(it's need for most tests). But I don't realy think that setUp can be run in other thread. Or I can be wrong?

Comment: Yan, yes I setting this variable in setUp block. This is junit test. This variable need for all other test but not for that, so I tried to clean it in the start of this test method. If I remove this from setUp this test will pass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a property is not defined in a `Properties` object, then `getProperty` will look up in the parent `Properties` object

[`Properties` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> ```
> public String getProperty(String key)
> ```
>
> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property list. **If the key is not found in this property list, the default property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked.** The method returns `null` if the property is not found.

`clearProperty` calls `Hashtable.remove` since `remove` is not overridden in `Properties` so does not affect the default property list.

So it is quite possible for a cleared property to still be visible via `getProperty` since the `System` javadoc does not specify whether system `Properties` are layered or flat.

Comment: Mike Samuel, you are right. Thank you. I found that in some legacy code use Properties constructor that init defaults.